# TP-Link WiFi router

Tags: installation, wan, pppoe

I'm trying to install a TP-Link wireless router. I am using a modem and have a PPPoE connection. I connected the router to the computer and the modem, but in the last step of the Easy Setup it says:

> Failed to verify router settings. 1. Please check the WAN connection type and parameters. 2. Please check your connectivity and retry.

The Internet works fine if I connect the modem directly to the computer. When I connect the computer to the router, the wireless network is detected by other devices, but cannot be accessed.

I accessed the router settings, and everything seems normal, except that it just says "Connecting...". It never manages to connect to the Internet. I tried restarting the router and several walkthroughs on the web, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Which model TP-Link Wifi router?  Try a firmware update for the router.  What setup information did your ISP give you?  Test new cable(s) between the router and modem and computer.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have made an error in how you connect the router to the modem. Either by its settings or by how the cables are connected.

Verify the following:

1. The modem goes from its LAN port to the router's WAN port
2. If you have not configured anything on your pc, use 2a, otherwise 2b.

   - 2a. In the configuration for internet, you set the IP to get one through DHCP, not static.
   - 2b. In the configuration for internet, you set the IP to static, and fill it in the same way as on your pc.
3. Make sure you set the connection type to PPPoE.